# MySQL select query if no records occurred in the last 12 months

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to create a Select query which will only show rows older than 12 months, if there's no record for the same column in the last twelve months. For example, my table looks like the following:

| id | supid | lastqual |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2019-01-08 |
| 2 | 1 | 2020-08-03 |
| 3 | 7 | 2019-09-14 |

The closest I've gotten is the following query

```
SELECT
  Suppliers.id,
  Suppliers.company,
  Qual.id,
  Qual.lastqual
FROM 
  Suppliers
  LEFT JOIN Qual ON Suppliers.id = Qual.supid
WHERE Qual.lastqual < DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 12 MONTH)
```

which returns row 1 and 3. However what I'm trying to get is a statement that will exclude row 1 from the Qual table, since there's also a record (row 2) which occurred inside of the last 12 months.

What WHERE statement can I include to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `NOT EXISTS` clause to check that no record exists in `Qual` for the same supplier `id` with a date in the last twelve months:

```sql
SELECT
  Suppliers.id,
  Suppliers.company,
  Qual.id,
  Qual.lastqual
FROM 
  Suppliers
  LEFT JOIN Qual ON Suppliers.id = Qual.supid
WHERE Qual.lastqual < DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 12 MONTH)
  AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT * 
    FROM Qual 
    WHERE supid = Suppliers.id AND Qual.lastqual >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 12 MONTH) 
)
```

Note that for comparing dates it's probably more appropriate to use `CURDATE()` (which just returns the current date) than `NOW()` (which also returns the current time as part of the value).

[Demo on db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mXmxkY9BL1rsu6hMMj6sLy/0)

Comment: Works like a charm! I didn't even now the NOT EXISTS clause existed. Thanks so much!

Comment: @Buster good to hear. Sorry about the typo, I've corrected that and added a demo link. It's worth looking into `EXISTS` and `NOT EXISTS` clauses, they can be a very efficient way of solving this type of problem.